# Does this define a continuously differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis

> Does the sum of series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin nx^2}{1+n^3}$
>   defines a continuously differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$

I know  that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin nx^2}{1+n^3} \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3+1}$ , so that series is unifromly convergent !

Answer (score 1):

The uniform convergence of the series

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin (nx^2)}{1+n^3}$$

gives you the continuity of the limit function. For the (continuous) differentiability, you need to consider the series of the differentiated terms

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2nx\cos (nx^2)}{1+n^3}.$$

If that series is locally uniformly convergent (it is; why?), its limit function is continuous, and the derivative of $f$, so then $f$ is continuously differentiable.